# Slick slider. Is there a way to check where slider slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

i'm using Slick slider on my page and I want to find out if there any way to check where slider slides, to the right or to the left, and then to do some action on this event?

Basically I have a check event only on custom arrow click, using data attr, but i wanted to know if I can find out it on swipe or when it slides automatically.

Here is a basic script for slider, that i use:

```
var arrowPrev = ('.a1');
var arrowNext = ('.a2');

$('.slider').slick();

$arrowPrev.click(function(){
 $arrowPrev.data('clicked', true);

  if($($arrowPrev).data('clicked')) {
    console.log('here')
  }
});

$arrowNext.click(function(){
 $arrowNext.data('clicked', true);

  if($($arrowNext).data('clicked')) {
    console.log('there')
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide the necessary code, ideally a jsFiddle demo, for us to be able to help you.

Comment: added, but don't sure that this will help somehow

Answer (score 3):

The slick slider has a couple of events you can use to detect this:

- `beforeChange`

```js
$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

- `afterChange`

```js
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
  console.log(currentSlide);
});
```

- `swipe`

```js
$('.slider').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log(direction);
  // left
});
```

For more info check the slick Events section under Settings on the official website of [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Answer (score -1):

To detect slick direction onBeforeChange event

infinte:true
centermode:true/false

```
var dir;
    if((currentSlide<nextSlide&&currentSlide==nextSlide-1)||(currentSlide==slick.slideCount-1&&nextSlide==0))
          {
               dir='right';
          }
    else if(nextSlide<currentSlide||(nextSlide==slick.slideCount-1&&currentSlide==0))
          {
             dir='left';
          }
    if(dir=='right')
    {
    //do something.
    }
    if(dir=='left')
    {
    //do something.
    }
```